When solving a paraxial Helmholtz equation ... ? Amplitude vs Wave function
Given the paraxial Helmholtz-equation (PHHE). Why are the solutions formed by the amplitude function of a wave function, but not the wave function itself? Example, a form of a wave function is defined $$ a(x) = A(x)e^{ikz} $$ with A(x) being the transversal profile/ amplitude function. Why does the explicit A(x) solves the PHHE and not the a(x). When deriving the gaussian beam, you also get a form of a wave function:
$$\large a(x) = A_0 \frac{w_0}{w(z)}e^{\frac{-r^2}{w^2}}e^{\frac{-ikr^2}{2R} }e^{-i(kz-arctan(z/z_0))}
$$. What term inside the wave function would solve the PHHE? Is there a way to imagine what is going on? Thank you

I'm not sure what is the par-axial Helmholtz equation. But consider the function
$$
a(x,z) = A(x) e^{i k z},
$$
and consider the Laplace equation
$$
∆ a(x,z) = \nabla^2 a(x,z) =\frac{\partial^2 a(x,y)}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 a(x,y)}{\partial z^2}= 0,
$$
simply applying this we get
$$
\frac{\partial^2 A(x)}{\partial x^2} e^{i k z} - k^2 A(x) e^{ikz} = 0,
$$
crossing out the exponential we get
$$
\left(\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}-k^2\right)A(x) = 0.
$$
Thus if $a(x,z)$ solves the Laplace equation and is in the form $a(x,z) = A(x) e^{i k z}$ then $A(x)$ solves the Helmholtz equation in the form given above.

Thank you, I understood the idea.

If I've answered the question pleace accept the answer by the green checkmark so that the question gets labeled correctly.
